# Does there exist $\{X_n\}$ for which $\liminf_{n\to \infty}X_n$ doesn't exist but the negative parts $\{X^-_n\}$ are uniformly integrable?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, examples-counterexamples, uniform-integrability

Are there random variables $\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ for which the expected value of $ \liminf\limits_{n\to \infty} X_n $ doesn't exist  **but** the negative parts $\{X^-_n\}_{n\ge 1}$  are uniformly integrable?

How can we prove analytically that there exists?

Comment: Just take a random variable $X$ which is non-negative and not integrable and set $X_n := X$ for all $n$. Since $X_n^- =0$ uniform integrability of the negative parts is trivial and $E(\liminf_n X_n) = E(X)$ does not exist because $X \notin L^1$.

Comment: which random variable would you choose?

Comment: Take e.e. $X(\omega) = \frac{1}{\omega} 1_{(0,1)}(\omega)$ on $\Omega=(0,1)$

Comment: Make sure your title agrees with the main question asked. (the existense of $\liminf X_n$ and the expected value of $\liminf X_n$ is not the same thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the classic example of a sequence of functions (random variables) that converges in measure to zero, but does not converge pointwise to zero (for any $x$), would be an example of what you asked.

---

Let $X_n=-\sqrt{\frac{1}{\mu(I_n)}}\cdot\chi_{I_n}(x)$, where $$\chi_{I_n}(x)= \begin{cases} 1 &x \in I_n \\
                     0 & x \notin I_n
\end{cases}$$

And $\{I_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is $[0,\frac{1}{2}],[\frac{1}{2},1],[0,\frac{1}{3}],[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}],[\frac{2}{3},1],[0,\frac{1}{4}],[\frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4}]...$

You get that $\liminf\limits_{n\to \infty} X_n = -\infty$ and therefore its expectation does not exist.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^1 X_nd\mu = 0$$

so you can prove they are uniformly integrable.